# U.S. president-elect impeachment trial before taking office?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, impeachment

Can a U.S. president-elect be impeached or have an impeachment trial begin before taking office?

Comment: Related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12828/can-an-elected-but-not-sworn-in-president-elect-be-impeached

Comment: I'm thinking semantically...no...can't really be impeached from an office you haven't taken.

Comment: @Philipp the other linked questions wasn't answered

Comment: Begs the question: Given that once impeached from any office precludes the officeholder from ever holding another federal office, could an ex Cabinet or other official be impeached after leaving office to prevent that person from holding future office?  Is "sitting" really a requirement?